# Abelian Varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

I have some questions about two statements from Bosch's "Algebraic Geometry and Commutative Algebra" about ***algebraic varieties*** (page 479):

[image]

W fix an abelian variety $A$ over field $K$. Here the definition

[image]

Following two questions:

1. Why is for a $K$-group scheme of finite type ***smooth*** equivalent to ***geometrically reduced***?
2. Why under same conditions as in 1.  (so $K$-group scheme of finite type) the property ***irreducible*** is equivlaent to ***geometrically irreducible***?

Comment: Also on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/324887/why-is-for-a-group-scheme-of-finite-type-smooth-resp-irreducible-equivalent-t